# Laravel: link to external files

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink, laravel-8

I am developing a page just for my company. We have VPN so all computers are on the same network.
So, I'm trying to see attachments from my server, but when I put a link in Laravel to see them it sends them like this:

The link is **\192.168.0.100\Adjuntos\Gerencia.docx** when I enter this link in Chrome it downloads it perfectly.
But Laravel redirect to **//Localhost:800//192.168.0.100\Adjuntos\Gerencia.docx** but it doesn't work obviously.

How can I redirect to these external links to view or download them?

I also see that the links are redirected to:
LocalHost:8080/file://192.168.0.100//Adjuntos//Hallazgo//IMG_1140.JPG

Answer (score 0):

If the following value is file then try this. make sure that the trailing slash is forward slash. eg file:///path/to/file

```
<a href="file:{{$Adj->HalAdPath}}">{{$Adj->Name}}</a>
```